# Change Custom Listview ImagButton Background

Tags: android, android-listview

My code is as following:

```
/* Here it's my custom listview getView Method .I have problem with for Change ImageButton Resources for while ImageButton Click in android. */
                @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
                @Override
                public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                    LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();


                 convertView=in.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings_difflevel,parent,false);


                TextView txtDiffLevel=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiffLevel);
                ImageButton imgDiffLevel=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgDiffLevel);
                map=result.get(position);

                if (position %2 == 0) {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6a35c"));  
                } else {
                    convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6b87a"));            }
                txtDiffLevel.setText(map.get("diffMap"));
                convertView.setTag(map.get("diffMap"));

                return convertView;
            }

 /* Here it's my custom listview getView Method .I have problem with for Change ImageButton Resources for while ImageButton Click in android. */
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            ImageButton imgDiffLevel=(ImageButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.imgDiffLevel);
            imgDiffLevel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkedlevel);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please explain in brief what you are trying to do and what you are getting. if you are getting any error, then please post the log cat.

Comment: i have problem for not change the background resource for imagebutton while listview item click

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This Code:-**


int MyPosition;    // this variable declare in class





    /* Here it's my custom listview getView Method .I have problem with for Change ImageButton Resources for while ImageButton Click in android. */
                    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
                    @Override
                    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        LayoutInflater in=getLayoutInflater();


                     convertView=in.inflate(R.layout.layout_settings_difflevel,parent,false);

    MyPosition = position;

                    TextView txtDiffLevel=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDiffLevel);
                    ImageButton imgDiffLevel=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgDiffLevel);
                    map=result.get(position);

if(MyPosition==0){

convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6a35c"));  

}else{

int x = MyPosition % 2;

if (x == 0) {
                     convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6a35c"));  

                }else if (x == 1) {
                     convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e6b87a"));            }

                }

}



                    txtDiffLevel.setText(map.get("diffMap"));
                    convertView.setTag(map.get("diffMap"));

                    return convertView;
                }

     /* Here it's my custom listview getView Method .I have problem with for Change ImageButton Resources for while ImageButton Click in android. */
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id) {
                ImageButton imgDiffLevel=(ImageButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.imgDiffLevel);
                imgDiffLevel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkedlevel);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you I have got Solution.But I have also remain previous Image on ImageButton while Click on next selected Item If you have then tell me?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            ImageButton imgDiffLevel=(ImageButton)parent.findViewById(R.id.imgDiffLevel);
imgDiffLevel.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.checkedlevel); 
//use setImageResource(R.drawable.imgDiffLevel); (or setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.imgDiffLevel));) instead of setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imgDiffLevel);.
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this in adapter getView() method itself:

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                imgDiffLevel.setImageResource(R.drawable.checkedlevel);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helped!

Edit:
use setTag()

like imgDiffLevel.setTag(drawable1)
and in onClick() methid

```
if((int)imgDiffLevel.getTag()==drawable1)
{
  imgDiffLevel.setImageResource(drawable2);
}
else
{
  imgDiffLevel.setImageResource(drawable1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but when i click second time of listview item at that time preview ImageButton image same as changeble I have required for the first time loaded image of imageButton